# Load balancing for web apps in Azure

Tags: reference, sample, azure-webapps, azure-load-balancer

We have deployed the ASP .Net web application with Microsoft Identity authentication. Now we are planning to implement the Load balancing for the same. Based on the MSDN reference link [load-balancing-overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/technology-choices/load-balancing-overview) we are planning to implement the AzureFront door + Application Gateway Can anyone shares the sample documents and reference for the same?

Answer (score 1):

**Preparing the App Service**

1. You Need to prepare the App Service to accept requests on the custom domain that routes through the Application Gateway.
2. Configure a custom domain in AppService.
3. Azure App Service Authentication requires HTTPS, so we need to configure an SSL certificate for our custom domain.
4. Next, we need to set up Azure Active Directory authentication using the **“Authentication / Authorization”** feature on the App Service.
5. If you configured your custom domain before setting up Azure Active Directory authentication, both your *.azurewebsites.net and custom domain URLs should be configured for the reply URLs.

**Setting up the Application Gateway**

1. First, before configuring the Application Gateway, ensure that you change your custom domain from pointing to the App Service to pointing to the Application Gateway's public IP or DNS name. This change is done in your DNS registrar.
2. This can be achieved by Azure PowerShell and the key part of the script that has been adjusted is with the backend HTTP settings. The default configuration for the backend HTTP setting uses **“-PickHostNameFromBackendAddress”,** which would use the ***.azurewebsites.net** hostname when connecting to the backend App Service. When that configuration is in place, authentication goes towards the *.azurewebsites.net hostname instead of the custom domain, causing authenticated users to be directed towards the *.azurewebsites.net hostname and bypassing the Application Gateway.

Here is reference blog for more clarity,

[Setting up Application Gateway with an App Service that uses Azure Active Directory Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/waws/setting-up-application-gateway-with-an-app-service-that-uses-azure-active-directory-authentication)